# How to get 'pipeline script from SCM' crendentials in pipeline script

Tags: jenkins

Internally I'm transferring jobs from one Jenkins server to another, but I've wondered this  when we need to change the permission on a job.

The option to check out from SCM has some credentials in it, shown in the image:

[image]

Is there a way to get the SCM checkout credentials from what is specified in the GUI level of the job, so i don't have to hard code the credential ID in the script.

Currently we have to sync the credential ID's ? This is annoying and error prone.

I've tried the normal [GIt Plugin Environmental Vars](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) but to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to restore the credentials if you don't know it, just write a simple pipeline that set environment variables for the user+password using WithCredential tag, and echo the values into a text file on the jenkins server. Then you can restore your user+password into a new credential on the new Jenkins server from the content of that file

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the SCM checkout credentials from what is specified in the GUI level of the job, so i don't have to hard code the credential ID in the script.

Yes. If you are using **Pipeline script from SCM**, you can get the Credentials ID with the following snippet:

```
scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getCredentialsId()
```

This is useful, for example, when you want to dynamically checkout a *Jenkins Library* using the same credentials you configure in the *Pipeline script from SCM* GUI.

```
library identifier: 'sample-jenkins-library@master', retriever: modernSCM(
        [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
        remote: 'https://github.com/repo/sample-jenkins-library.git',
        credentialsId: scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getCredentialsId()])
```

*Please keep in mind that libs loaded this way aren't considered trusted. Not exactly part of the question, but very valuable info if you got here with the intention of implementing exactly that!*

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the library credentials ID within the pipeline script.

The best you can do is get the version (branch name) for the library. For example, `env.getProperty("library.<NAME>.version")` where `<NAME>` is the name of your shared library.

I had to migrate jobs to a new Jenkins instance and ran into this same issue. The only silver lining is that I now reference credential IDs using string constants where possible so that future updates are simple.

Job migration is a tedious process, and managing credentials can be difficult. Once you have many credentials defined it can be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You could just migrate all the credentials from the old Jenkins instance to the new one before you start configuring the jobs. Then delete what you don't use later, if needed.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001634268-How-to-migrate-credentials-to-a-new-Jenkins-instance-